# socket.io error net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl, socket.io

This is my client code.

```
const socket = io(url);
```

This is my server code on linux server with express server.

```
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
```

When I try to connect, the error occures.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should change in `url` var data. From `https` to `http`